# Enclose with double quotes and separated by comma in csv file

Tags: c#

I used this code to omit the quote and to split with comma.
I have a content of csv file like this data.
ex: 
"1111","05-24-2017","08:30","0","TRAVEL"   
"2222","05-25-2017","08:20","0","TRAVEL"

I used this code:

```
   public bool ReadEntrie(int id, ref string name)
    {
        int count = 0;
        CreateConfigFile();
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(data_path, FileMode.Open);
            sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            bool cond = true;
            string temp = "";
            while (cond == true)
            {
                if ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) == null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    cond = false;
                    if (count == 0)
                        return false;
                }
                if (count == id)
                {
                    string[] stringSplit = temp.Trim('\"').Split(new 
                    String[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    //string[] stringSplit = temp.Split(',');
                    int _maxIndex = stringSplit.Length;
                    name = stringSplit[0];                       
                }
                count++;
            }
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is the expected output

Comment: Backwards : temp.Split(new String[] { "," }, 
   StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray();

Comment: I want to display the data into my form that compose of textbox, datetimepicker,combobox.I encounter an error upon reading the field of datetimepicker.It is becuase the format of csv file is enclose with double quote while in the form there is a custom format to the datetimepicker I set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The problem is not on that function. It is by other function and I used trim 
for it.                                                            
string[] stringSplit = temp.Split(',');
int _maxIndex = stringSplit.Length;
name = stringSplit[0].Trim('"');
lastname = stringSplit[1].Trim('"');
phone = stringSplit[2].Trim('"');
mail = stringSplit[3].Trim('"');
website = stringSplit[4].Trim('"');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *don't have* **commas** or **quotation marks** as a part of data e.g.

```
"12,34","56","a""bc"   ->  12,34   56   a"bc
```

you can put a simple *Linq*:

```
 string[][] result = File
   .ReadLines(@"C"\MyData.csv")
   .Select(line => line
      .Split(',')
      .Select(item => item.Trim('"'))
      .ToArray())
   .ToArray();
```

Further improvement is to return an array of a tailored class:

```
 MyClass[] result = File
   .ReadLines(@"C"\MyData.csv")
   .Select(line => line
      .Split(','))
   .Select(items => new MyClass() {
      Id = items[0].Trim('"'),
      Date = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1].Trim('"') + " " + items[2].Trim('"'), 
                                "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm",
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
      Code = items[3].Trim('"'),
      Text = items[4].Trim('"'), 
    }) 
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: When I used ReadLines command. I encounter error the File are used by the other application.

Comment: @Sam: check your code: it seems that you don't close the file somewhere in your application. Another possibility is that the file is opened by MS Excel or something which opens it for writing (and thus wants exlusive access)

Comment: Alright.I got  your Idea about Trim. I works right now.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple function. It will take care of double quote and comma between double quotes.

```
private string[] GetCommaSeperatedWords(string sep, string line)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    int doubleQuoteCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
    {
        string chr = line[i].ToString();
        if (chr == "\"")
        {
            if (doubleQuoteCount == 0)
                doubleQuoteCount++;
            else
                doubleQuoteCount--;

            continue;
        }
        if (chr == sep && doubleQuoteCount == 0)
        {
            list.Add(word.ToString());
            word = new StringBuilder();
            continue;
        }
        word.Append(chr);
    }

    list.Add(word.ToString());

    return list.ToArray();
}
```